# Is there a way to tell at runtime if a class is part of the Flex API or the Flash Player API?

Tags: flash, apache-flex

Is there a way at runtime to determine if a class is part of the Flex API or part of the Flash Player API?

For example, the class, "flash.display.DisplayObject" is part of the Flash API while, "mx.core.FlexSprite" is part of the Flex API.

All I have to work with is the name of the class, "flash.display::DisplayObject" or "mx.core::FlexSprite".

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding you need to get the class names, you can get the class names and super class names from flash utils.

```
public static function getClassName(c:Class):String
{
trace("Class Name :: "+getQualifiedClassName(c)+" Super Class Name :: "+getQualifiedSuperclassName(c));
//trace("Describe Type"+describeType(c).toString());
var superClassName:String =  getQualifiedSuperclassName(c).replace("::", ".");
var className:String =  getQualifiedClassName(c).replace("::", ".");
return className;
}
```

Comment: Per the original question; he already has the class names.  "All I have to work with is the origina name of the class".  I don't understand how any of the code provided here will help him determine which library the code comes from at compile time.

Comment: based on the class or super class name prefix's flash.* or mx.* , we will know that the class is from Flex or flash API right ?

Comment: Not definitively.  Because nothing prevents me from creating my own class and putting it in a flash.* package or mx.* package.  There are also a bunch of Flex classes that are not in an mx package; such as the whole spark component set.

Comment: yeah i accept, we can use the same package structure like mx.* or spark.* ... then how to identify those class ?